# how to check window scrollTop on svelte project?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte, visual-web-developer

I'm working on a svelte project and I'm having issues getting the window scrollTop value when I scroll the website...

I tried running this code in the svelte page route:

```
<script>
    function checkScroll() {
        console.log("Scrolled");
    }
</script>
<svelte:window on:scrollX={checkScroll}/>
```

When I run this on dev server console remains empty..
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or not doing...

Comment: Scrolling happens on the client, so you will never see that in the dev server console. If anything, check the browser dev tools console, but `scrollX` is not an event and the wrong axis.

Comment: @H.B. how do I increase the opacity of an element in increments as I scroll?

Comment: You should have asked that in the question itself, not a comment. Ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the value directly to a variable [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-window-bindings)

```
<script>
    let x //to the right
    let y //down
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollX={x} bind:scrollY={y}/>
```

or listen to the event like this depending on your needs

```
<script>
    function handleScroll(event) {
        console.log('scrolling')
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:scroll={handleScroll}/>
```

Comment: `scrollX` is the wrong axis, by the way.

Comment: @H.B. true, I only saw the `scrollX` and didn't notice the mentioned `scrollTop`